# Steam opengl glx context is not using direct rendering

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, steam, opengl

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 with the latest Nvidia drivers installed. However, when I run steam I am presented with the following message:

```
steam opengl glx context is not using direct rendering
```

I believe this is something to do with not having the correct 32 bit library, however I did install the Nvidia 32 bit libraries when I installed the driver. Running Steam from the terminal I can see that Steam is failing to find the 'swrast' driver which it shouldn't be looking for anyway.

Comment: I just yesterday read somewhere that a user reported on his system software rendering was used, and the advice was to add that user to the `video` group. He reported back that this fixed the issue for him . I don't know if yours is the same problem, but probably worth a try. (Sorry, but I really don't remember where I read that.)

Comment: I've just added myself to that group and I'm still having the same issue - thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: To anyone reading this later, don't forget to log off and log back on after adding yourself to the video group, so that your permissions get updated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing and purging my previous Nvidia driver and upgrading to the latest beta Nvidia Driver 334.16. I also installed a number of 32 bit libraries which were suggested on various websites which might have contributed to the resolution of this problem.